# How to call Await functions inside Realm.open function?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, realm

i was trying to integrate Realm db to my project

```
Model File : 

export const CHAT_LIST_SCHEMA = {
  name: 'ImList',
  properties: {
    name: 'string',
    rid: 'string',
    lastMessage: 'string',
    time: 'string',
  },
};
```

```
Code : 

init = async () => {
    try {
      Realm.open({ schema: CHAT_LIST_SCHEMA }).then((realm) => {
        let cachedData = realm.objects('ImList');
        console.log('Cached Data', cachedData);
        if (cachedData === '') {
          console.log('called123');
          this.setState({ data: cachedData });
        } else {
          console.log('called');
        const result = await RocketChat.getIMlist(); // API Call
        const data = await RocketChat.getRoomsList(result); // Filtering
          realm.write(() => {
            data.map((items) => {
              realm.create('ImList', {
                name: items.name,
                rid: items.rid,
                lastMessage: items.lastMessage,
                time: items.time,
              });
            });
          });
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

But it shows I cant call await outside an async function, but I only need to get data from the API, if the DB is empty. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put async on the wrong function. The one waiting for async methods is arrow function inside `.then` statement, so it should look like:

```
init = () => {
    try {
      Realm.open({ schema: CHAT_LIST_SCHEMA }).then(async (realm) => {
        let cachedData = realm.objects('ImList');
        console.log('Cached Data', cachedData);
        if (cachedData === '') {
          console.log('called123');
          this.setState({ data: cachedData });
        } else {
          console.log('called');
        const result = await RocketChat.getIMlist(); // API Call
        const data = await RocketChat.getRoomsList(result); // Filtering
          realm.write(() => {
            data.map((items) => {
              realm.create('ImList', {
                name: items.name,
                rid: items.rid,
                lastMessage: items.lastMessage,
                time: items.time,
              });
            });
          });
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

btw. you can also await the Realm.open function -> less nesting :)

Comment: Thanks man! also have u used realm DB with react native? coz I'm trying to integrate a local DB with my app, and the docs online arent that good. Could really use some help.